# php mvc search implementation

Tags: php, search, get, url-routing

I am starting to use a php minimal MVC implementation. But with MVCs I am finding it hard to pass parameters in GET method using traditional HTML form.

For example my mvc path call is "`www.example.com/?route=products/search/balck shirt`".

and I would like to pass search term "black shirt" in GET method using a html form.

```
<form method="GET" action="www.example.com/?route=products/search/">
<input type="text" name="src" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This would result in a call as "`www.example.com/?src=black%20shirt`". I am losing `"?route="` part of it. How can I work around this? I know POST is the preferred method, but in natural websites search terms should be appended to the url so that the links can be shared elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify which "mvc" framework you are using.

Comment: It is a custom one... built by some one at http://www.henriquebarroso.com/ which was known as 2kb MVC

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure the GET param gets [urlencoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) . This will lead to the url www.example.com/?route=products/search/black%20shirt (note the %20)

Comment: GET values are already encoded when you submit a form with `method="get"`. I believe the problem is that the OP is losing the `route` argument. When the form is submitted.

Answer (score -1):

send as get request with js/jquery and construct the url as needed by your mvc, if I understood your question correctly, you need to make it work with the mvc.

```
<form action="javascript:;">
<input type="text" name="route" value="products/search/">
<input type="text" name="src" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").on("click",function(){

        if($("input[name='src']").val().length>0)
        {
            window.location=$("input[name='route']").val() + $("input[name='src']").val();
        }

    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Serhio Miller! Is there an alternative for this other than using java script? Or do you know of any other MVC model where this problem is handled in a different way...

Comment: if you dont care for the route part to not have the "src" appended to it, then you can construct your html as:

<form method="GET" action="www.example.com">
<input type="text" name="route" value="products/search/">
<input type="text" name="src" />
<input type="submit" />

and this will send example.com/?route=products/search/&src=black%20shirt
</form>

Comment: I just tried that... Looks like I will have to use one of above approaches... Thanks...

Comment: -1: for `<form action="javascript:;">` and jquery where none is required